OpenDKIM Isn't building with OpenSSL correctly
I am trying to build OpenDKIM from source. For some reason, the build is not supporting SHA-256, even when the OpenSSL version I am building with uses SHA-256. How is this possible ?
I run:
./configure --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl/ssl

Then make and make install as usual. Checking opendkim -V shows the only supported algorithm is sha1. What is going wrong ?
I have tried build with the latest stable OpenDKIM version 2.10.3 and the pre-release 2.11.0. Both have the same error.
Is openssl somehow not being correctly linked ? I am really stuck here - any help is appreciated !

OpenDKIM is broken & no likely to be no longer supported. The last commit is over 6 years old. In saying that, opensuse do have some patches for it if you search on their site for the source as well as browse the issue list on github.

Thankyou for you comment. I am aware OpenDKIM is an old project - do you know what has taken its place ? I am struggling to find alternatives to what seems a crucial component of SMTP, that being SHA-256 encryption ?
I believe the opendkim bug could be due to opendkim not finding the correct openssl libraries. I have tried building OpenSSL as a shared install - opendkim says it cannot link against a static openssl install. Any ideas ?
Without any luck I will be writing my own Postfix encryption interface for OpenSSL, as I have SHA256 working on the CLI...
